# Having problems running script getting error: if event.type == pygame.QUIT: syntax Error

Tags: python, syntax

So I'm following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vg83OtRkevE
and  I've done everything the  tutorial told me to but I'm still getting this error message when I run it:

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

syntax Error
```

(this was made in repl.it)
my code is:

```
import sys

WIN_WIDTH = 800
WIN_HEIGHT = 600
TILESIZE = 32
FPS = 60



class Spritesheet:
  def __init__(self, file):
    self.sheet = pygame.image.load(file).convert()

    def get_sprite(self, x, y, width, height):
      sprite = pygame.Surface([width, height])
      sprite.blit(self.sheet, (0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
      return sprite

class Ground(pygame.sprite.sprite):
  def __init__(self, game, x, y):
    self.game = game
    self._layer  = 1
    self.groups = self.game.all_sprites
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)

    self.x = x * TILESIZE
    self.y = y * TILESIZE
    self.width, self.height = TILESIZE, TILESIZE
    self.image = self.gane.terainsheet.get_sprite(0, 96, self.width, self.height)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x, self.rect.y = self.x, self.y
    

def build_map(self, tilemap):
  for i, row in enumerate(tilemp):
    for j, column in enumerate(row):
      Ground(self, j, i)

class Game:
  def __init__(self):
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
    self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    self.running = True
    self.terrainsheet = spritesheet(('terrain1.png'))

    def createTilemap(self, tilemap):
      build_map(self, tilemap)
      def new(self, tilemap):
        self.playing = True
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
        self.createTilemap(tilemap)

        def events(self):

          for event in pygame.event.get():
            if eve nt.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self.playing = False
            self.running = False

  def update(self):
    self.all_sprites.update()

    def draw(self):
      self.screen.fill('black')
      self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
      self.clock.tick(FPS)

      pygame.display.update()

  def main(self):
    while self.playing:
      self.Events()
      self.updates()
      self.draw()
     
    TILEMAP = [
        '............................',
      '............................',
      '............................',
      '............................',
      '............................',
      '............................',
      '............................',
      '............................',
      '............................',
      '............................',
      '............................',
      '............................',
      '............................',
      '............................',
      '............................',
      '............................',
      
    ]
    game = game()
    game.new(TILEMAP)
    while game.running:
      game.main
      pygame.quit
      sys.exit()
```

At first it was some other syntax error I had to fix, If anyone is able to help please do!
I'm a newbie to pygame so sorry if my question seems stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python needs indentation in order to know the scope of each section (eg. if, while, for, function, etc.). Here is comprehensive guide how to do it properly: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/. If your code is indented as in your question. There is a problem here:

```
          for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # This If is empty
            self.playing = False # this
            self.running = False # and this does not belong to that If
```

it must be indented according:

```
          for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              self.playing = False
              self.running = False
```